# MSSQL Table valued functions: Replacing a function definition

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a bunch of queries where I'd like to replace an existing logic with a join from another logically deduced table (via a table valued function)

I'd like to write a table valued function which acts as a "stub" for now using some hard-coded values, so that when the actual function is available, I'll "swap" out the stub with the real function

Here's my code for the stub:

```
create function dbo.stub(@dt date)
returns @ReturnTable table ( colA varchar(50) , colB varchar(50) )
as begin

insert into @ReturnTable (colA,colB) values ("abc", "def")

end;
```

The problem is I won't know the name of the real function upfront (given by someone else), so I need to use a "wrapper" in all the aforementioned queries such that the wrapper returns

1) the stub until the real function is known

2) the real function when its implementation is known

Note: it's fine to assume that both the stub and the actual function will have identical return table structures

So I need a logic such as:

```
create function dbo.wrapper( @dt date )

returns dbo.stub(@dt date)
```

when I am using the stub and then:

```
create function dbo.wrapper( @dt date )

returns dbo.realFunc(@dt date)
```

when the real function (realFunc) is available

The idea being that all my queries can just bank on the `dbo.wrapper`, without having to worry about whether they are getting the table to join from stub or the real function

The last 2 syntaxes dont work for me...

Can anyone point out how I should define my wrapper in the light of above code and examples above?

Comment: Just a warning, with multi statement UDFs, you might have performance issues, since functions are called row-by-row like cursors and you won't have correct row count estimates for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    create function dbo.wrapper( @dt date )
    returns @return_value date
    as begin
    set @return_value = dbo.stub(@dt)
    end
```